# Background image not appearing on simple webpage

Tags: css, background-image

This should be really easy and basic but I can't for the life of me figure it out...

Very simple web page #1 is here:

http://www.lowhandicapper.com/ytlp04

I am trying to make a copy of it on a new domain with just minor changes to the link urls.

Here's the new page:

http://perfectimpactsystem.com/lp027

I can't seem to get the background image to appear on the pefectimpactsystem page! In chrome dev tools it shows the background link but it is crossed out with a yellow warning sign next to it.

Also in firefox the formatting is all messed up.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `background` rule the first apostroph in the URL is actually a backtick (`). Replace it with an apostroph and it works fine.

In practice you can delete both the backtick and the apostroph since they're not required in a `url(link)` value.

Answer (score 0):

This line is in your new site's CSS file:

```
background: url(â€˜http://perfectimpactsystem.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/bgTomIron.jpg') no-repeat center top;
```

Notice the odd characters at the start of the URL where the apostrophe should be.

Change your code to this, and you should be set:

```
background: url('http://perfectimpactsystem.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/bgTomIron.jpg') no-repeat center top;
```

Good luck!